# group and order in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have to write a query in which I need the given output.
I tried different queries but didn't work.

Actual data :

[image]

and I need Output like : 
[image]

Queries like :

```
SELECT VCD.id,VCD.effective_date, `VCD`.`charge_id`, `C`.`head`, 
`VCD`.`per`, `VCD`.`currency`, `VCD`.`amount`, `VCD`.`remarks` 
FROM `vendor_charge` `VC` INNER JOIN `vendor_charge_details` `VCD` 
ON `VC`.`id` = `VCD`.`vc_id` LEFT JOIN `charges` `C` 
ON `C`.`id` = `VCD`.`charge_id` 
WHERE `VC`.`vendor_id` = '12' AND `VCD`.`effective_date` <= '2018-05-22' 
GROUP BY `VCD`.`charge_id`, `VCD`.`per`, `VCD`.`currency` 
ORDER BY `C`.`head` DESC
```

and

```
SELECT VCD.id,VCD.effective_date, `VCD`.`charge_id`, `C`.`head`, 
`VCD`.`per`, `VCD`.`currency`, `VCD`.`amount`, `VCD`.`remarks` 
FROM `vendor_charge` `VC` INNER JOIN `vendor_charge_details` `VCD` 
ON `VC`.`id` = `VCD`.`vc_id` LEFT JOIN `charges` `C` 
ON `C`.`id` = `VCD`.`charge_id` 
WHERE `VC`.`vendor_id` = '12' AND `VCD`.`effective_date` <= '2018-05-22' 
GROUP BY `VCD`.`charge_id`, `VCD`.`per`, `VCD`.`currency` 
ORDER BY `VCD`.`effective_date` DESC
```

Comment: Please take a few moments and fix your formatting.  Then, include your sample input and output data directly in the question.  _Do not paste links._

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm new to here, I have not that much of Badges to include the image in direct post.

Comment: Don't include images.  Period.  Type out your data, in table format.

Comment: ok, now please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need here is an additional join to a subquery which finds the latest `effective_date` for each `charge_id`:

```
SELECT
    VCD.id,
    VCD.effective_date,
    VCD.charge_id,
    C.head,
    VC.per,
    VCD.currency,
    VCD.amount,
    VCD.remarks
FROM vendor_charge VC
INNER JOIN vendor_charge_details VCD
    ON VC.id = VCD.vc_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT charge_id, MAX(effective_date) AS max_effective_date
    FROM vendor_charge_details
    GROUP BY charge_id
) t
    ON VCD.charge_id = t.charge_id AND VCD.effective_date = t.max_effective_date
LEFT JOIN charges C
    ON C.id = VCD.charge_id
WHERE VC.vendor_id = '12' AND VCD.effective_date <= '2018-05-22'
ORDER BY
    C.head DESC;
```

Comment: if I want to group by charge_id, per and currency column than what to do?
The effective date is dependent on this three parameters

Comment: I have no idea what you have in mind.  Typically, you would only use `GROUP BY` if you needed to aggregate something, but you haven't told me what that might be.  I recommend opening a new question, as this one has been answered.  Stack Overflow is not a blog site.